# WooCommerce backend product filters not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem with the filtering of products in the backend.

There are 92 products in a specific category - when I select it and press filter it will show only 10 products from that category.

If I go to Products > Categories and click on the number 92 I will be shown 92 products from that category.

This site was updated from a very old version of WordPress and WooCommerce (it was done while ago - no issues reported then).

I tried to disable plugins and switching themes - nothing helps.
There are no errors in console either.

This is the URL that I am getting after pressing the Filter button.

`/wp-admin/edit.php?s&post_status=all&post_type=product&action=-1&seo_filter&readability_filter&product_cat=rolly-toys&product_type&stock_status&filter_action=Filter&paged=1&action2=-1`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try clearing transients. Go to `WooCommerce > Status > Tools` then the button next to `WooCommerce transients`

Comment: I tried that, didn't work. Thanks

Comment: I found the exact issue - and its not related to WooCommerce. The Screen options work incorrectly. It shows max of 10 items per page.